# Assign a dynamic array type to a TArray<T> variable

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to assign a dynamic array type to a `TArray<string>` variable

```
type
  TMyStringArray = array of string;

function Test() : TMyStringArray;
begin
  ...
end;

...

var
  MyArray : TArray<string>;
begin
  MyArray := Test();
end;
```

On compiling, Delphi says:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(39): E2010 Incompatible types:
>   'System.TArray' and 'TMyStringArray'

Comment: This issue is covered in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)) in the "Array Types and Assignments" section: "*Arrays are assignment-compatible only if they are of **the same type**.*" `TMyStringArray` and `TArray<string>` are NOT the same type.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, it should be pointed out already here that `TArray<string>` *is* a dynamic array of strings; it's defined as `array of string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it simply by using a type cast and it seems to work.

I would be glad to know I can fall into some problems doing this way

```
type
  TMyStringArray = array of string;

function Test() : TMyStringArray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 2);
  Result[0] := 'Hello';
  Result[1] := 'World';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyArray : TArray<string>;
  i : integer;
begin
  MyArray := TArray<string>(Test());

  i := 0;
  while(i < Length(MyArray)) do
  begin
    ShowMessage(MyArray[i]);
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. `TArray<string>` is defined as `array of string`, so it *is* a dynamic array of strings, just like `array of string` (obviously). So it is undesirable and strange that the compiler refuses to consider these types compatible without the cast.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I'm using Delphi XE7, does the newer versions accept the assignment without the type cast?

Comment: I actually thought that was fixed in 10.3, but now I tried it, and it seems not. I still need to cast. (I know *something* changed very recently related to this, but I don't quite recall what it was.) But this is how the type system works. Try, for instance, to define `type
  TDynStringArray = array of string;
  TDynStringArray2 = array of string;`. They will not be assignment compatible without a cast...

Comment: The best solution these days, I think, it to always use `TArray<string>` as the dynamic string array type. (It is better than `array of string`, for instance, because it can be used as a function return type. And it is better than any user-defined type defined as `array of string` because it is part of the core RTL, so all units agree on it.)

Comment: @Fabrizio "*does the newer versions accept the assignment without the type cast?*" - in your example, no.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*I know something changed very recently related to this, but I don't quite recall what it was*" - pre-existing dynamic array aliases were redefined to use `TArray<T>`, thus becoming assignment-compatible with each other..

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, that might very well be it. I recall seeing code with several overloaded functions that suddenly became indistinguishable from each other. Thanks!

Comment: Anyhow, forcing the assignment using a cast does work, and is safe, as far as I know. If you look at the internal data of the dynamic array, you can see that the reference count is managed correctly. So to answer Fabrizio's question: yes, this is safe and shouldn't lead to any issues (unless you manage to cast to an incorrect type by mistake, of course). Do you agree, @RemyLebeau?

Comment: `Types.TStringDynArray` and `TArray<String>` are assignment compatible nowadays.

Comment: @LURD: Indeed, `Types.TStringDynArray` is now defined as `TArray<string>`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes, type-casting one dynamic array type to another dynamic array type *of the same element type* is safe, since they use the same internal structure.

Comment: Remove the `TMyStringArray` type, and every type defined that way, and use `TArray<T>` everywhere